# Texture painting my model from 2D .jpeg picture or better solution

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

How to realistically paint horse model? Is best option texture paint from image, and how to do it for the mane and the tail

Comment: Is this the tutorial you watched? I know it is an older version, but the tools are about the same function since nothing has changed in Texture Paint tools yet. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4ngVoGIj1Q

Comment: Hello. I watched a lot of them, also watched this but got me confused so I asked for help. But maybe I just need more practice and experience with texture paint. Thanks!

Comment: Your post has several questions in it but needs to be a specific question we can answer. If you can edit it down to a specific question, we can try to illustrate here how we approach it, and you can ask a new question post for any other specific point you have trouble with. I try to monitor the paint questions and answer best I can, but vague questions are impossible.

Comment: Ok sorry then. Now I fixed I hope it is clearer. Thanks